# How to specify the hyperparameter space?

Tags: python

I was wondering what it takes to define a parameter on GridSearchCV for ElasticNet (it's my first time with ElasticNet). This is the first part of my code. The original code is from DataCamp course.

Now here's my question: what it takes to define this specific parameter "elasticnet__l1_ratio" on the code underneath? Is it correct to define as `np.linspace(0,1,30)`? it seems arbitrary as I took the code to apply to my dataset, besides the data being standardized by the 'scalar' function.

```
X = full_df.drop('SharesFloat', axis=1)
y = full_df['SharesFloat']

# Setup the pipeline steps: steps

steps = [('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')),
         ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('elasticnet', ElasticNet())]
         
# Create the pipeline: pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
```

(# Specify the hyperparameter space) - How to define it? What do I take into account?

```
# Specify the hyperparameter space
parameters = {'elasticnet__l1_ratio':np.linspace(0,1,30)}

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=42)

# Create the GridSearchCV object: gm_cv
gm_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)

# Fit to the training set
gm_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute and print the metrics
r2 = gm_cv.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Tuned ElasticNet Alpha: {}".format(gm_cv.best_params_))
print("Tuned ElasticNet R squared: {}".format(r2))
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to set the hyperparams or about the actual values you need for the hyperparams?

Comment: What should I take into account when deciding it. Should I care about the values of my dataset, number of variables, etc? I want to understand so I can apply to my data

Comment: I would suggest that you post this question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.